# How to download software without Secure Download Manager (SDM)? How to open .sdx files?

Tags: download

How can I download software without using Microsoft's "Secure Download Manager" (SDM)?

I am trying to download software from the "Microsoft Imagine" education software website, but I've checked out multiple products at once, and now they want me to use a special program to download them.

They only give me a `.sdx` file and a link to a program (named "Secure Download Manager") which can open it.

How can I avoid using this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the file using [your favorite text editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/).
2. Open a new tab in some browser (I'm using Chrome).
3. Paste `view-source:` into the address bar.
4. Go to [your text editor of choice](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and copy the one and only line in the `.sdx` file.
5. Paste the copied text (from the file) right behind the text already in the browsers address bar (`view-source:`) and hit enter (append the URL).
6. In the browser, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and enter the name of your download (eg. "Visio").
7. Look for a result inside of an `<input type="hidden"` HTML tag.
8. You should have the result highlighted inside text looking something like this: `http://dl.msdn.com/db/de_visio_pr`
9. Copy all the text between the quotation marks(`"`) after the text `FileURL=` and copy it.
10. Paste it in [your prefered text editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and do a replace-all (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), replacing all `&amp;` with `&`, leaving only the `&` in the URL behind.
11. Copy and paste the text back into the browser.
12. Hit enter and wait for the download.